# Mysql multiple values in a cell

Tags: mysql, database, datatable, foreign-keys

I'm trying to figure out how could I have some values that are foreign keys to other table, but I think it can not be done that way.

Here is my example:
I'm working with some repairing reports. Those reports contains info about what has been repaired and how many components have been replaced. There are some codes that codify the trouble that has been repaired and also for the components. Those codes can be one or several, and I want to store all troubles in a column of my reports table but I think that can't be done.

I've thought that I can create an intermediary table that will contain only 2 columns, Id of the report and then the trouble code, and it will have one entry for each trouble. Same with components.

That way I could know all troubles for each report, but I would need to do 5 querys to print out the report with the troubles and the components.

So I've searched if I can do it in one cell but only info I got is using varchar values and then split them and look for the codes translation in a table ,that has code, description, one by one.

So is this the only way to achieve it or is impossible to create a multi reference from a table to others?

I'm surely your answer will be yes, do it as a varchar, but just to be sure.

P.D: Sorry if it's a bad question, bit new.

Comment: do you use any programming language to process and insert the data into the database? Like Java, C# . . . .etc.?

Comment: Right now I'm at creating DB, doing it in phpmyadmin and it will be PHP,JavaScript and jQuery code to generate transactions

Comment: Okay good, please check my answer below, and if you need further explanation (or my answer is not very clear), let me know.

Comment: 1. Please show the design where you think you "need to" do 5 queries (joins?). Because there seems to be more to what you need than you are explaining. 2. It is a relational anti-pattern to put the multiple values in one column instead of using another table. 3. You have naive/unjustified/uninformed notions of space-time tradeoffs of designs. 4. This appears to be a combination of two faqs, multi-/complex-/array-/list-/set-valued columns and database subtying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a many to many relationship to me.

You can use a table for reports, a table for troubles and a table report_troubles which holds foreign keys to reports and troubles.

A single query like `select * from report_problems where report_id = 2` would give you all the info.

Comment: Yes, It is, but that table could become so big, if I have 5 reports, each report have 10 problems=50entries on the table. I'm sure that I will have 100+ reports a month, so I think I need to use the other solution

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem for the next 10 years. Alternatively you could try some nosql database but the overall size would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Given the case you just stated - as you said - you can create another table that has two columns, one for the id and the other for the codes, of course it will not be redundant because id + code (code is of course unique) will be also unique.

All you have to do is just query all the codes from the other table using the id you have.

If you want to somehow store the codes within the same table, then you have two choices:

1. As you mentioned, store the codes as varchar values (string values) and concatenate these codes in one string using delimiters, something like this:

> $codes = code1 . ',' . code2 . ',' . code3 . ',' . code4 ..... and so
>   on.

so your delimiter is the "comma", you can store the string in the database, and then retrieve it and explode it to split the codes using the delimiter (comma). BUT if your string will consist of a lot of codes (so it will be large) use TEXT instead of varchar....maybe LONGTEXT if you need to, but check first with yourself which datatype you would need and do some searching on that.

Note: instead of using string to concatenate the codes, you can use a simple array, and then use implode on that array to add separator (delimiter) between the values. However, if you are not sure that your codes would include something similar to your delimiter and afraid to get messed up, then head to the second point below.

---

2. The second way is to store your codes in an array (using php) and each time you get a new code for the same id, just add it to the array, like that :

> $arr = array();
>
> $arr[] = code1;
>
> $arr[] = code2;
>
> $arr[] = code3;

and then (using php) serialize the array using serialize() :

```
$serialized_arr = serialize($arr);
```

and then store the $serialized_arr into your database, the column to store this data must be of type TEXT or LONGTEXT (or might even BLOB).

then, when you have a new code that you want to add, just do this:

```
$unserialized_arr = unserialize($serialized_arr);
```

Now you have retrieved the serialized text from your database, unserlialized it and now you can deal with it (using php) as an array ($unserialized_arr), just add the new codes to it, and then serialize again and update your database.

Of course here the $serialized_arr that you will unserialize will be the text stored in your database, so you will first retrieve it from your database.

For more information about which datatype to use, refer to this link:

[Which mysql column type for serialize(data)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770974/which-mysql-column-type-for-serializedata)

Have a good day =)

Comment: Wow, nice and very complete answer, it will help me a lot, now I need to calculate what choice should better, but I think text codes will do. Thanks a lot